# How to get keys in a PHP array with null values?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

When I print an array with a string as `$key` and an array as `$value` using `foreach ($array key => value)`, the keys with `null` values are not displayed. Can someone please help me with this?

```
$stockist = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   
    $pharmacy = trim($row['pharmacy']);
    if (isset($stockist[$pharmacy])) {
        $medicine = $stockist[$pharmacy];
        $medicine[] = trim($row['pharmacy']);
        $stockist[$pharmacy] = $medicine;
    }
    else {
        $medicine = array();
        $medicine[] = trim($row['medicine']);
        $stockist[$pharmacy] = $medicine;
    }
}

ksort($stockist);
foreach ($stockist as $key => $value) {
    echo "<table align='center' border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><td align = 'justify'> <font color = 'blue'> $key</td></tr>";
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        echo "<tr><td align ='justify'>$value1</td></tr><br>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: please add your code to your post

Comment: can you test this `array_dump($stockist);` and post the resulting array, so we can see what is in it?

Comment: I need another table to display keys with no values to match.Just the key names are needed. Is it possible with var_dump?

Comment: @JorgeCampos what's `array_dump()` ?! new functions I see...

Comment: What do you want to see in case the value is null?

Comment: I just wanna see the variable in $key

Comment: @revo Sorry I mean `var_dump`

Comment: @revo,@JorgeCampos
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'CANNANORE DRUG CENTRE-KNR' (length=25)
      1 => string 'CANNANORE DRUG HOUSE-KNR' (length=24)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it is what the title is asking for ("How to get keys in a PHP array with null values?"--my own question that brought me to this page):

```
function find_nulls($a) {
    return array_keys(array_filter($a, function($b) {
       return is_null($b);
    }) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop instead of foreach.

```
$stockCount = count($stockist);
for ($stockCount; $i <=0; $i++) {

  echo "<table align='center' border='1'>";
  echo "<tr><td align = 'justify'> <font color = 'blue'> $stockCount[$i]</td></tr>";


  echo "</table>";

}
```

Hope it will work.